SQLAlchemy not retrieving data from schema.sometable
I am having trouble having the query produce results. I know there is 1 value in the table, but I cannot get the data to show in Python.
I am also not getting any errors in the run.
I have the following code.
db = sa.create_engine("/url")
Session = sessionmaker(bind=db)
Base = declarative_base()

class SomeTable(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'schema.sometable'

    tId = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    PlanCode = Column(String(50), primary_key=True)
    cId = Column(Integer)
    lId = Column(Integer)
    ModifiedDate = Column(DateTime)
    ModifiedChange = Column(String(50))

def main() -> None:
    Base.metadata.create_all(db)

    with Session() as session:
        result = session.query(SomeTable).all()
        print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Sql Table schema is :
tId is Int
PlanCode is Nvarchar(50)
cId is Int
lId is Int
ModifiedDate is DateTime
ModifiedChange is Nvarchar(50)

I have tried removing the Primary Key constraints for tId and PlanCode in SQL, adding them back in as both nonclustered and clustered.
I have made many changes in the python code and much of the time it has ran but when calling "count()" it shows "0" or when calling "all()" is shows "[]"
I am unable to get a data to show in python, I am also using Microsoft SQL.
What changes can I make to get the data to show?

Try using sa.create_engine("/url", echo=True) and then check the log output to see the actual SELECT statement that is generated by your session.query(SomeTable) call.

class SomeTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_schema.sometable'


will not work as you might expect. It will look for the data in a table called [some_schema.sometable] in the default schema for your database connection. I suspect that you want to do
class SomeTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sometable'
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "some_schema"}



Yes, the "some_schema" is not the default schema, and was what I was missing. Thank you so much!
